# Call query from another query in MySQL and fetch into only 1 JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, json.net

I want to call and select query to another query from another table and send in only one JSON. I got 2 tables (`towing_list` and `towing_info`)

json get method

```
[{"towing_id":"51","towing_username":"tow","towing_latitude":"3.7310769",
"towing_longitude":"103.1240930","distance":"0"},
    {"towing_id":"56","towing_username":"tow1","towing_latitude":"3.7311311",
"towing_longitude":"103.1239854","distance":"0.013374089073083037"}]
```

i want to use "towing_username" and call their detail from another table wish are their "towing_fullname" and "towing_contactnumber" so it will get this json result below:

```
[{"towing_id":"51","towing_username":"tow","towing_fullname":"tow_name",
"towing_contactnumber":"0123456789","towing_latitude":"3.7310769",
"towing_longitude":"103.1240930","distance":"0"},
{"towing_id":"56","towing_username":"tow1","towing_fullname":"tow1_name",
"towing_contactnumber":"01518191904","towing_latitude":"3.7311311",
"towing_longitude":"103.1239854","distance":"0.013374089073083037"}]
```

My Table

```
towing_list : (towing_id,towing_username,towing_latitude,towing_longitude)
towing_info : (towing_id,towing_username,towing_fullname,towing_contactnumber)
```

this is part of my code

```
$q = "

SELECT  * , (
    6371 * acos (   
      cos ( radians($lat) )
      * cos( radians( towing_latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( towing_longitude ) - radians($lon) ) 
      + sin ( radians($lat) )
      * sin( radians( towing_latitude ) )
    )   ) AS distance FROM towing_list WHERE `towing_status`='$status' HAVING distance < $total_dis_miles   

ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20 ";

$r = mysql_query($q);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($r)) {  $array[]=$row; }

echo json_encode($array);
```

Is it possible to do?. I m new to JSON. Please help..

Comment: hi, i would say this has a little to do with json, rather geting the data which you encode into it. If you provide structure of your database and what you want obtain, i am pretty sure, the data you want can be obtained through one query :)

Comment: i got 2  table .. First table is towing_list with column name (towing_id,towing_username,towing_latitude,towing_longitude) . Second table is towing_info with column name (towing_id,towing_username,towing_fullname,towing_contactnumber) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use join

```
$q = "SELECT * , ( 6371 * acos (
cos ( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( towing_latitude ) ) * cos(radians( towing_longitude ) - radians($lon) ) + sin ( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( towing_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM towing_list INNER JOIN towing_info ON towing_info.towing_id = towing_list.towing_id WHERE towing_status='$status' HAVING distance < $total_dis_miles
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20 ";
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vama_v1/Towing_list_user/user_list_towing.php on line 26
[]

Comment: $q = "SELECT * , ( 6371 * acos (
cos ( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( towing_latitude ) ) * cos(radians( towing_longitude ) - radians($lon) ) + sin ( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( towing_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM towing_list INNER JOIN towing_info ON towing_info.towing_username = towing_list.towing_username WHERE towing_status='$status' HAVING distance < $total_dis_miles 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20 ";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($r))
 {
  $array[]=$row;
 }

 echo json_encode($array);